# gunicorn +flask + linux azure web app + Invalid subcommand '-debugAdapter' during the warmup of the app

Tags: linux, azure-web-app-service, gunicorn

thank you in advance for the time you will invest by helping me.

## the use case

- this is an app using flask and python.
- the web app runs on Linux on Web App hosted by Microsoft Azure
- An error message is triggered when the Web App starts:

```
Error: Invalid subcommand '-debugAdapter'. Available subcommands: version, create-script, setupEnv
    chmod: cannot access '/opt/startup/startup.sh': No such file or directory
    /opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 75: /opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory
    ERROR - Container <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>_0_5c14e0e1 for site <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME> has exited, failing site start
    ERROR - Container <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>_0_5c14e0e1 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
    INFO  - Stopping site <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME> because it failed during startup.
```

## the files and command lines

### Azure > App Service > Configuration > GENERAL settings

the Startup Command is : `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 "flaskr:create_app()"`

### Azure > App Service > Configuration > APPLICATION settings

```
[
  {
    "name": "FLASK_APP",
    "value": "src/flaskr",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "7",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_PORT",
    "value": "8000",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

### requirements.txt

```
    click==7.1.2
    pytest==5.4.2
    pytz==2020.1
    pandas==1.0.3
    numpy==1.18.1
    requests==2.23.0
    altf1be_helpers==2.0.0
    Flask==1.1.2
    Werkzeug==1.0.1
    python-dotenv==0.13.0
    requests-toolbelt
    bleach
    docutils
    Pygments
    gunicorn
```

### run_app_prod.sh

This is the shell script that runs on my local machine and successfully runs the web app locally

the directory 'src' contains the source code of the flask application

```sh
#/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
echo current $DIR

python -m pip install -e src

./test_if_db_exists.sh

export FLASK_APP=src/flask

gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 "flaskr:create_app()"
```

## The error message

```
INFO  - Starting container for site
INFO  - docker run -d -p 6256:8000 --name <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>_0_5c14e0e1 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=<LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME> -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=<LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=3151e080d60036e54d871e3a77271d20e2070c8a9e16315ff09f2d444a2e8afb -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/python:3.7_20200522.6 gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 "flaskr:create_app()"
INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>_0_5c14e0e1 for site <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>

_____
/  _  \ __________ _________   ____
/  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
/    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
\____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
        \/      \/                  \/

A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X

Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
Python 3.7.7
Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 "flaskr:create_app()"
App will launch in debug mode
Launching oryx with: -debugAdapter ptvsd -debugPort 49494 create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -bindPort 8000 -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 "flaskr:create_app()"'
Error: Invalid subcommand '-debugAdapter'. Available subcommands: version, create-script, setupEnv
chmod: cannot access '/opt/startup/startup.sh': No such file or directory
/opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 75: /opt/startup/startup.sh: No such file or directory
ERROR - Container <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>_0_5c14e0e1 for site <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME> has exited, failing site start
ERROR - Container <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>_0_5c14e0e1 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
INFO  - Stopping site <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME> because it failed during startup.
```

## the log files from the LOCAL machine (the working configuration)

```
./run_app_prod.sh 
start run_app_prod.sh
current /home/<username>/dev/bb/sca-tork-easycube-api
Obtaining file:///home/<username>/dev/bb/sca-tork-easycube-api/src
Requirement already satisfied: click==7.1.2 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytest==5.4.2 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (5.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2020.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas==1.0.3 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.18.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests==2.23.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altf1be_helpers==2.0.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask==1.1.2 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug==1.0.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dotenv==0.13.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (0.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-toolbelt in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (3.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (20.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0,>=0.12 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools>=4.0.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.5.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==1.0.3-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests==2.23.0-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests==2.23.0-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests==2.23.0-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests==2.23.0-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: Unidecode==1.1.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from altf1be_helpers==2.0.0-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask==1.1.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask==1.1.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bleach-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from bleach-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from gunicorn-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (47.3.1.post20200616)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from packaging->pytest==5.4.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/<username>/miniconda3/envs/azurelinuxapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask==1.1.2-><LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app==0.1.0) (1.1.1)
Installing collected packages: <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app
Attempting uninstall: <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app
    Found existing installation: <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app 0.1.0
    Uninstalling <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app-0.1.0:
    Successfully uninstalled <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app-0.1.0
Running setup.py develop for <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app
Successfully installed <LINUX_AZURE_WEB_APP_NAME>-web-app
src/instance/flaskr.sqlite already exists no need to create it.
[2020-06-25 10:37:02 +0200] [13762] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-06-25 10:37:02 +0200] [13762] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (13762)
[2020-06-25 10:37:02 +0200] [13762] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-06-25 10:37:02 +0200] [13765] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13765
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the answer but The final configuration is the following:

## application settings

```
[
  {
    "name": "FLASK_APP",
    "value": "src/flaskr",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
    "value": "true",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "7",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_PORT",
    "value": "8000",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

## startup command

```
./run_app_prod.sh
```

### ./run_app_prod.sh

```
#/bin/bash

echo "start run_app_prod.sh"

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

echo current $DIR

python -m pip install -e src

./test_if_db_exists.sh

export FLASK_APP="flaskr:create_app()"
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 "flaskr:create_app()"

echo "end run_app_prod.sh"
```

## General issue corrected by Carlos Bazilio

[Carlos Bazilio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142878/carlos-bazilio) did help me address the general issue which was a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskr' : [Azure + gunicorn + flask + Azure Web App Linux: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flaskr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62505643/azure-gunicorn-flask-azure-web-app-linux-modulenotfounderror-no-module-n/62602276#62602276)